# Windows 10 VLAN tagging

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, vlan

In previous versions of Windows we could install the Intel Advanced network drivers in our notebooks to connect to specific VLANs via the embedded Ethernet adapter.

In Windows 10, the option is not available and there is a message that says:

> Intel(R) Advanced Network Services (Intel(R) ANS) Teams and VLANs are
>   not supported on Microsoft* Windows* 10

Is there any way to enable this functionality in Windows 10, or is there a USB adapter that has this functionality in Windows 10?

Laptop is a Dell Latitude 5580 with an Intel I219-LM Ethernet adapter running Windows 10 Professional edition.

[image: Intel VLAN Configuration screen]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to enable this functionality in Windows 10, or is
>   there a USB adapter that has this functionality in Windows 10?

You need to install the drivers that support this feature, you must install the version of the drivers that specifically, indicate support or this feature if you are running Windows 10 1703.

[image]

Here is what the release notes indicate for the driver in question.

> ## Intel(R) ANS Teams and VLANs on Microsoft* Windows* 10
>
> If you are running **Windows 10 Anniversary edition (RS1)** you will need to install **Intel LAN software v22.1 or newer**. If you are running **Windows 10 Creators Update (RS2)** you will need to install **Intel LAN software v22.3** or newer. Note: If you are running Windows 10 Creators Update (RS2) and are using Intel LAN software release v22.1 or v22.2, then ANS will not function until you update to the Intel LAN software v22.3 or newer.

It is worth pointing out that you will want to defer Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (RS3) until an updated driver for this device is released.

Source:

- [Intel® Network Adapter Driver 22.6 for Windows® 10](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25016/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10)
- [Downloads for Intel® Ethernet Connection I219-LM](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/82185/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I219-LM)

Comment: I have provided a link to the current version (22.6) but I won't be updating the answer (the driver will be updated several times in the next few months due to 1709 being released in Oct).